# Where is the default download directory in Tor Browser?

Tags: browsers

When I mention the default download directory, what I mean is the directory where Tor places files downloaded from the internet, and *not* the directory where Tor itself is downloaded when updated.

I know this default location may vary depending on the system, so let me tell you that I'm using Tor Browser 12.0.4, installed on Debian Bullseye Stable using APT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I mention the default download directory, what I mean is the directory where Tor places files downloaded from the internet, and not the directory where Tor itself is downloaded when updated

If you download Tor Browser the usual way (https://www.torproject.org/download/), the directory where Tor places files downloaded from the internet is actually *inside* the directory where Tor itself is downloaded. So if you downloaded and unpacked Tor Browser to `~/tor-browser`, then downloads would be in `~/tor-browser/Browser/Downloads`.

> I know this default location may vary depending on the system, so let me tell you that I'm using Tor Browser 12.0.4, installed on Debian Bullseye Stable using APT.

Since you installed Tor Browser using `apt`, I'm not sure where it would be stored. Tor Browser isn't in the Debian apt repositories, so did you add some other repository? Or did you use torbrowser-launcher? If you used torbrowser-launcher, check the directory where it downloaded Tor Browser.

Edit from the OP:

Normally, you can find this directory quite easily by going to `about:preferences` and searching for `downloads`. There is a setting for changing the downloads directory, just like in Firefox, where you can see what your present directory is. If this setting has never been changed, then it will show the default directory. In the case where Tor *has* been installed using the Tor Browser Launcher, by adding the official Tor repos to Debian, the default directory in Debian Bullseye is `~/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/Downloads`.